# How to inherit a List from a parent class from a child class in java

Tags: java

How to inherit a List from a parent class from a child class ?
this is parents Class code

```
public class PageList extends Page {
    protected List<String> LectureName = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

and this one is child class

```
public class Connect extends PageList{
   // try to check it pass 
   protected void GetConnection(){
   for(int i =0;i<7;i++){
          System.out.println(LectureName.get(i));
   }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't works. why i can't inherit a List from parent class?

Comment: What is not working? Be specific, please.

Comment: @just-another-java-programmer  that print parts doesnt' work.

Comment: Explain: "but it doesn't works"

Comment: Why do expect there to be 7 elements when you don't add any?

Comment: i add 7 elements. not describle in there.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error you probably receive is not related to inheritance. You can't just put the for loop directly into a class. Put it inside a method or constructor.

Edit: Now you get a runtime exception because you attempt to print the first seven elements of the list but the list does not contain any elements.Call LectureName.add(...) to add some elements to the list. Then use `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) System.out.println(list.get(i));` to print all the elements you added.

Comment: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: You are trying to access the first seven elements in the list, but this cannot succeed since the list is empty. To iterate through all elements in a list, you should use `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)`. This loop stops as soon as you have reached the end of the list.

Comment: i tried and figure out that list.size() == 0 .

Comment: Yes, because you don't put any elements into the list. Call LectureName.add(...) to add some elements to the list. Then use `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) System.out.println(list.get(i));` to print all the elements you added.

Answer (score 0):

Since you neglected to define "it doesn't work", we cannot diagnose your problem. I could guess you have a problem because of the instantiated list being empty (not populated). No way to know for sure.

But to answer your larger question…

Yes, a class can inherit a `List` member field from its superclass.

See this example [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/e4npUS).

```java
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Child child = new Child() ;
        child.printOut() ;
    }
}

class Parent {
    List< String > names = List.of( "Alice", "Bob", "Carol" ) ;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void printOut () {
        for( String name : this.names ) {
            System.out.println( name ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Alice
Bob
Carol
```